# Как найти число из заданного диапазона по условию? Python

Tags: python, функции, список

```
for call in range(1, 999999999999999):
    def col(n):
        sp = [n]
        if n < 1:
            return []
        while n > 1:
            if n % 2 == 0:
                n = n // 2
            else:
                n = 3 * n + 1
            sp.append(n)
        for i in sp:
            print(i, end = ' ')
    col(int(call))
```

Нужно чтобы программа искала такое число, у которого в списке нету цикла `4 2 1`. Я представил это так: У каждого числа из диапазона есть свой список чисел, например у 5 это - `5 16 8 4 2 1`, если выполняется функция для числа 5, то на экране будут эти числа. Программа по гипотезе Коллатца.
Я представил это так, что программа будет проверять каждый такой список и искать такой, где нету цикла `4 2 1` и вывести на экран такое число, с таким списком.
Как такое можно написать в питоне?

Comment: 1) Вынесите определение функции за цикл; 2) Преобразование `int(call)` излишнее; 3) Этот цикл будет выполняться порядка **10 тысяч лет** в `Google Colab`, и то это по первым прикидкам, с ростом чисел, наверное, и `ETA` будет расти.

Answer (score 2):

Прежде всего стоит отметить, что на сегодняшний день лишь два числа не оканчиваются на `4 2 1` — это, собственно, 2 и 1. Кроме того, Вы указали в качестве верхней границы `10^16 - 1` хотя, если верить [данным от «Collatz Conjecture»](https://boinc.thesonntags.com/collatz/high_steppers.php), уже проверили числа большие, чем `10^23`, и при этом все эти числа удовлетворяли теореме Коллатца.

Впрочем, это было небольшое лирическо-математическое отступление, а касательно данной задачи могу сказать, что в конце функции `col` нужно проверить последние три члена списка на равенство с другим списком, `[4, 2, 1]`. Это можно сделать при помощи срезов:

```py
if sp[-3:] != [4, 2, 1]:
    print(call, sp) # мы можем написать call вместе со списком
                    # т.к. функция находится в одной области видимости с call
```

Касательно того, почему можно не проверять вообще ВЕСЬ список: если список сойдётся к 1, то наименьшая последовательность `4 2 1` — после неё идёт она же, и так до бесконечности. Остальные последовательности больше + включают в себя `4 2 1`, поэтому достаточно обойтись лишь указанной выше.